# Connected to VPN but unable to ping hosts on remote network

Tags: networking, raspbian, vpn, route, xl2tpd

I have PC2 connected to a VPN (L2TP/IPsec) server I have setup on R2. I need PC2 to be able to ping PC3 and PC4, but it's not working. When I use a Windows machine to connect to the VPN I can ping hosts under R2, but that is not the case with my Linux machine (Raspbian Jessie). I believe the solution has to do with the routing table but I have no idea what I am doing there.

I know that I am connected to R2 from PC2 because when I type 192.168.1.1 into the browser I am greeted with the remote router's login screen.

[image: Networking diagram]

PC2 is 192.168.1.125 under R1, and it is 192.168.1.69 under R2.
The public IP for R2 is 76.73.240.120. Here is the current routing information:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# ip route show
default dev ppp0  scope link
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0  metric 303
76.73.240.120 via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.125  metric 303
192.168.1.1 dev ppp0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.69
```

What do I need to do in order to get PC2 to be able to ping the hosts under R2?

Answer (score 2):

This looks a mess! First things first, routers connect *different* networks together. As a simplification, if things are on the same network then they should be able to talk to each other directly. You have 2 networks 192.168.1.0/24. The simplest solution would be to renumber one of them (PC1, PC2, R1) to be 192.168.2.0/24.

Let us say that PC3 is on 192.168.1.10.

The reason it is a problem is that you have 3 rules for how to get to PC3, one of them because it matches the `192.168.1.0/24` and two because it matches the `default` rules  which could also be written 0.0.0.0/0 (once via the ppp0 interface (the tunnel) and once via the wlan0 interface).

The rules are ranked in order, because 24 is more than 0 it is more specific, and hence is used.

So this routing table says that PC2 can communicate directly with PC3 via the wlan0 interface. so when you `ping PC3` it uses your wireless card.

If you renumbered PC1, PC2 and R1 to be on the 192.168.2.0/24 network then the rules for where PC2 become much simpler. If the packet has to go to 192.168.2.0/24, then send it via wlan0, otherwise send it to 192.168.1.1 via ppp0.

To get to 192.168.1.1 there are 4 choices 0.0.0.0/0 via ppp0, 0.0.0.0/0 via wlan0, 192.168.1.0/24 via wlan0 and 192.168.1.1/32 via ppp0. The /32 route is the most specific and hence is chosen, which explains why you see R2.

You *could* add extra routes for PC3 and PC4, something like

```
ip route add 192.168.1.10/32 dev ppp0
ip route add 192.168.1.11/32 dev ppp0
```

and hope that R2 sorts things out enough to enable packets to come back, but renumbering is much simpler.